# Is there a sample using Nelder-Mead solver in Microsoft Solver Foundation?

Tags: c#, optimization, sample, solver, ms-solver-foundation

I have been checking the examples that come with Microsoft Solver Foundation for an example using the Neler-Mead solver.  The samples website says there is one, but when I open the NLP sample written in C#, all I see is the Compact Quasi-Newton solver example called SineX.

Anyone find the sample in question, or have any other samples using the Nelder-Mead solver?

MSF Sample list on MSDN (shows two NLP samples, but I only see one)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524501(v=vs.93).aspx

Comment: According to the sample list, there only seem to be Nelder-Mead samples  for Excel.

Comment: If you are willing to skip using MSF, try DotNumerics (free download with source code):  http://www.dotnumerics.com/Downloads.aspx   Their library has an Nelder-Mead Simplex solver, with sample code, and it was easy to read and follow. I figured out in 10 minutes what five hours of web searching failed to teach me about MSF.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look at dot numerics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solver Foundation samples do not appear to contain any explicit Nelder-Mead examples in C#. However, you can easily test Nelder-Mead in the *SineX* sample by replacing the compact Quasi-Newton solver and parameters with their Nelder-Mead correspondents:

```
var solver = new NelderMeadSolver();
...
var param = new NelderMeadSolverParams();
```